# Как вызвать выплывающее меню листбокса на Windows планшете?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Имеется `ListBox` и привязанное к нему `PopupMenu` *(Delphi XE7, VCL)*. При нажатии правой кнопкой мыши меню вызывается, а при долгом нажатии стилусом (или пальцем) на планшете - нет.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите пример кода, это поможет быстрее понять как можно помочь

Comment: А кода пока нет! На форме есть ListBox и PopupMenu, связанное с ListBox. Хотелось бы понять, как вызвать это PopupMenu на Windows планшете долгим нажатием стилуса или пальца. Мышью оно вызывается.

Comment: Поиграйтесь с опциями свойства `Touch` вашего `ListBox`.

Comment: Весь день сегодня только с ними и играюсь)) Подозреваю, что в Delphi опять что-то не доделали... Интересно, что в Delphi 7, где никакого свойства Touch нет, все прекрасно работает((

Comment: В других программах это работает? Может быть у вас ОС настроена как-то иначе и не транслирует долгое нажатие пером в ПКМ.

Comment: Работает во всех контролах, кроме ListBox и ComboBox. Проверял на планшете HP с Windows 8.1 со всеми установленными обновлениями. Кроме того, если компилировать в Delphi 7, тоже все работает. Проблема именно в Delphi XE7.